# Use For loop to extract certain columns from a series of files to write new tab-delimited files

Tags: bash, for, file-management

I have a series of files located in a series of folder, for example:

```
~/BR2_1-3/bin.1.permissive.tsv
~/BR2_1-3/bin.2.permissive.tsv
~/BR2_1-3/bin.3.orig.tsv
~/BR2_2-4/bin.1.strict.tsv
~/BR2_2-4/bin.2.orig.tsv
~/BR2_2-4/bin.3.permissive.tsv
~/BR2_2-4/bin.4.permissive.tsv
~/BR2_3-5/bin.1.permissive.tsv
~/BR2_3-5/bin.2.permissive.tsv  
~/BR2_3-5/bin.3.orig.tsv        
~/BR2_3-5/bin.4.orig.tsv
~/BR2_3-5/bin.5.permissive.tsv
...
```

What I want to do is to extract the 1st and 5th column from each of the *.tsv files and create a new tab delimited file in the corresponding folder. That I can do separately for each file under its corresponding folder by using the commands below:

```
$ awk -F '\t' 'OFS="\t" {if ($5 != "") print($1,$5)}' bin.1.permissive.tsv > test
$ sed -i '1d' test
$ mv test BR2_1-bin.1.permissive.ec
```

My question is, because I have over a hundred of this kind of file, is there a way to write a `for` loop to do this step at the terminal automatically?

The naming convention for the folder and files are as follows:
"BR(2~5)_(1~6)-(n, as the number of files contained in the folder)" for the folders;
"bin.n.(strict/permissive/orig).tsv" for the files.

One input file should be mapping to one output file. The name for an output files is "BR2_1-bin.1.permissive.ec" if the corresponding input file was "~/BR2_1-3/bin.1.permissive.tsv". And the name for an output file is "BR2_3-bin.3.orig.ec" if the corresponding input file was "~/BR2_3-5/bin.3.orig.tsv". In addition, the output file is supposed to be written in the same folder with its corresponding input file.
Thanks for this question from the comment.

Thank you in advance and all suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Please be more clear in your statements.Is one file mapped to one in the output or is it a many-one mapping? Your output file naming convention is not explained so do tell us about that. Bcoz otherwise the answers might not be accurate.

Comment: one input file should be mapping to one output file. The naming convention for output file is "BR2_1-bin.1.permissive.ec" if the corresponding input file was "~/BR2_1-3/bin.1.permissive.tsv". Thank you for this question. I do want that the output files can be named following the input file naming conventions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `BR2_3-bin.3.orig.ec` without `-5` then?

Comment: Yes Freddy you are right. it should be BR2_3-bin.3.orig.ec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` and `xargs` are typically recommended for this:

```bsh
find "$HOME" -name \*.tsv |
  xargs awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '$5 != "" {print $1, $5}' >> output.tsv
```

or, more safely

```bsh
find "$HOME" -name \*.tsv -print0 |
  xargs -0 awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '$5 != "" {print $1, $5}' >> output.tsv
```

find's `-print0` directive prints out the matched files separated with a null byte, and xargs's `-0` options uses the null byte to separate filenames. This is done because the null byte is not allowed to appear in filenames, while newline is a valid character.

---

OK, for each file to be processed into the corresponding `.ec` file:

```bsh
find "$HOME" -name \*.tsv -print0 |
  xargs -0 awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    FNR == 1 {
      if (ec) close(ec)
      ec = gensub(/\.tsv$/, ".ec", 1, FILENAME)
      next
    }
    $5 != "" {print $1, $5 > ec}
  '
```

Notes:

- `print ... > ex` -- similar to redirection in the shell, this redirects the output to the filename contained in the `ec` variable.

  - unlike the shell, this does not overwrite the file for every "print", but only the first print truncates/creates the file and all subsequent prints append to it.
- You can run into "too many open files" errors, so it's best practice to `close` an open file when you're done with it.

  - do this when you're at the first record of a file
  - if the `ec` variable is not empty, it holds a filename that was used for the *previous* file that was processed
- `gensub` is a gawk-specific function, similar to `sub` and `gsub`. it's [described in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gensub_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029-1)

  - unlike `sub` and `gsub`, `gensub` *returns* the transformed value.

Comment: Hi glenn, Thank you so much for providing this piece of mind and it did work for most part! However, and sorry for not explicitly stating this in my original post, my bad, the outputs of all input files went into the "output.tsv" by appending, each set of output starts with its header and they are hard to be separated and matched to its original input files. Could this be done with some extra flags in xargs or it actually requires another command to be combined with?

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much glenn!!! Could you explain the scripts a little bit, especially for the section:"FNR == 1 {
      if (ec) close(ec)
      ec = gensub(/\.tsv$/, ".ec", 1, FILENAME)}$5 != "" {print $1, $5 > ec}
    }"? I really wanna learn something for the future. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much!!!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: +1.  I'd suggest `FNR > 1` as an extra condition for the second expression (or just adding `next` as the last statement in the first expression) - either will eliminate the need for `sed -i 1d` later.

Comment: Did I miss a requirement that the output files must not have a header?

Comment: The OP's example had 3 steps that they wanted to automate with a for loop - `awk ...`, `sed -i '1d'`, `mv ...`